# Install Maven Library on (ADF) Databricks Job Cluster

Tags: maven, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

I've tried using `/databricks/spark/bin/spark-shell --packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.13:3.4.1_0.19.0` in my init script, however I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main /databricks/spark/bin/spark-class: line 101: CMD: bad array subscript`.

I also tried using `.config("spark.jars.packages", "com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.15.0")` in my SparkSession initialization as below, but it looks like the config is getting ignored.

```
from delta import configure_spark_with_delta_pip
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

builder = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("oms-xml-streaming")
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.15.0")
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    .config("spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled", True)
)
spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

Workspace Libraries have been deprecated so I cannot download the JAR to my workspace and copy it to `/databricks/jars/` either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using the UI, can the jars not be added as dependent libraries ? it will install on the job cluster that way....

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula - Yes.

Comment: @rainingdistros - I want a programmable way of doing it, so I don't have to depend on the UI. I may have other maven libraries to install and I'm trying to create a generic ADF linked Service for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Data Factory, libraries for Databricks are specified on the task level, not on the linked service level. Create a task (notebook/jar/python) and then you'll be able to specify libraries for it in the "Settings" tab of the task properties, like this:

[image]

If you're using a connection to an existing cluster, then you need to install libraries to it.

Comment: Perfect Answer - Also wanted to refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/cluster-libraries#:~:text=(Not%20recommended)%20Install%20a%20library%20using%20an%20init%20script%20that%20runs%20at%20cluster%20creation%20time.%20See%20Install%20a%20library%20with%20an%20init%20script.) - `(Not recommended) Install a library using an init script that runs at cluster creation time. See Install a library with an init script.`

Comment: @rainingdistros - Thank you for pointing me to the documentation. I wanted to avoid the ADF UI and instead used the init script, because I wanted a generic way of installing libraries on demand, using environment variables passed via the linked Service. 

As mentioned above, ```/databricks/spark/bin/spark-shell --packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.13:3.4.1_0.19.0``` inside the init script resulted in an error.

Comment: I even tried using the Databricks REST APIs ```/api/2.0/libraries/install``` to request the library installation which succeeded with a 200 status, however ```/api/2.0/libraries/cluster-status``` never returned an ```INSTALLED``` status for the library which remained in ```PENDING``` status.